# Google Plus Vertical Sidebar Menu

Tags: jquery, google-plus

I really like current vertical menu/icons on Google+ (where it says Home, Profile, Explore...). It's there all the time and easy to navigate.

Does anyone know if there's any JQuery plugin that does similar job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u find any answers to this question ?